# Not getting full range of months in Jquery Date Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I've taken over someone's modifications to the call to the jQuery date picker.  The problem I'm having is that when I pass in today as the min-date and a year from now as the max date, the Year column shows 2015 & 2016, as it should, but the Month column only shows this month forward to December. All of the months before the current month are missing.

I'm not sure if my min-date that I pass in should just be changed to the first day of this year?  Or can I change this JavaScript to still show all the months, even if the min-date is today?

```
function createDatepicker($field) {
    var minDateStr = $field.attr('data-min-date').split('-');
    var maxDateStr = $field.attr('data-max-date').split('-');
    var minDate = new Date(parseInt(minDateStr[2]), parseInt(minDateStr[0])-1, parseInt(minDateStr[1]));
    var maxDate = new Date(parseInt(maxDateStr[2]), parseInt(maxDateStr[0])-1, parseInt(maxDateStr[1]));
    var div = $field.parent();
    var sy = $('.datepicker-year', div).first();
    var sm = $('.datepicker-month', div).first();
    var sd = $('.datepicker-day', div).first();
    $field.datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '-' + minDate.getFullYear() + ':+' + maxDate.getFullYear,
        minDate: minDate,
        maxDate: maxDate,
        showOn: 'button',
        firstDay: 1,
        beforeShow: function (obj, inst) {
            var year = parseInt(sy.val());
            var month = parseInt(sm.val());
            var day = parseInt(sd.val());
            if (year > 0 && month > 0 && day > 0) {
                if (month < 10) month = '0' + month;
                if (day < 10) day = '0' + day;
                $(obj).datepicker('setDate', month + '/' + day + '/' + year);
            }
        },
        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
            if (dateText != undefined && dateText.length > 0) {
                var date = dateText.split('/');
                var year = parseInt(date[2]);
                var month = parseInt(date[0]);
                var day = parseInt(date[1]);
                sy.val(year);
                sm.val(month);
                sd.val(day);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Well, if min-date is today it **should** be supposed to show from today until december, no? If you want to show the rest of the year then you should provide min-date as the first day of this year.

Comment: For this year, yes, that is correct. But the user should also be allowed to select a date such as Jan 1, 2016.  Right now, they can't.  The max-date is a year from today.

Comment: Hmm... can you please make a fiddle to work on? as long as maxDate is correct it should allow the user to take dates in 2016, from january 1st to the maxDate included.

Comment: OOH wait, `maxDate.getFullYear`. missing `()` after `maxDate.getFullYear`. Also, is the + in ':+' intentional?

Comment: Ah! Hang on and let me test that!!!

Comment: As briosheje stated it is because of the missing `()`, which causes a bad `yearRange` value: http://jsfiddle.net/uyk557da/

Comment: yearRange:  minDate.getFullYear() + ':' + maxDate.getFullYear(),

Comment: I changed to the above.  Still only shows June to December.

Comment: Actually in the fiddle provided by PatrickEvans it seems to be working. Moreover, reading from the documentation (http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/), about the year range:  _Note that this option only affects what appears in the drop-down, to restrict which dates may be selected use the minDate and/or maxDate options._

Comment: I stand corrected.  The missing () WAS the problem.  If you select 2016, the month range changed from Jan to June.

Comment: briosheje - create and answer and I'll select is correct.  Thanks!

Comment: @PatrickEvans : I think you deserve the answer because you created the fiddle, hence you should post an answer containting the fiddle, I've just found out that the parenthesis were missing, but wasn't really sure that it could've been the true problem, while patrick tested it, so he deserves the reputation for that answer ;)

Comment: @briosheje, Actually it should be closed as typographical error, seeing as OP knew to put the `()` on the other getFullYear statement

Comment: You guys are both awesome.  I was too close to the code... should have seen that myself.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of this line:

```
yearRange: '-' + minDate.getFullYear() + ':+' + maxDate.getFullYear,
```

Worked for me.

Comment: This line needs to be here because we are using the same script for a Birth Day date picker, and we need to specify that the years go back 120 years.